# Github Workflow with workflow_dispatch not starting on "run workflow"

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to create a new github workflow and have `workflow_dispatch` as one of the triggering options. When I go to `Actions` I can see my workflow and click "Run workflow" which results in a "Workflow run was successfully requested." notification at the top of the screen. However, nothing happens after I click it. Any ideas why that might happen?

My github action is defined here: https://github.com/Mrc0113/test-github-workflow/blob/main/.github/workflows/checkStartSpringIO.yml

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the github workflow eventually ran so it was likely just an issue with the github GUI not showing an action was pending.